# vba excel locks all cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a woorkbook that includes several vba sub-routines. One of theese routines makes changes to a worksheet after the user checks a checkbox. The problem is that after the code is run all cells are locked, even if not marked to be locked in the Format cells -> Protection menu. However if I bring up VBE and execute the code msgbox Range("C24").Locked, the unlocked cells are editable again.

The code follows:

```
Sub cbAcertos_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulário")

Call unProtectWindow

If Me.cbAcrescimo Then
'Caso tenhamos acrescentado o valor de acréscimo por refeição do AEV
    If Me.cbAcertos Then
    'E seja necessário efectuar algum acerto
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Desligamos a actualização do ecrã
        With Range("F30")
            .ClearContents
            .Value = "Valor Acertos:"
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'Inserimos as etiquetas de texto
        With Range("G30")
            .Formula = ""
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'Preparamos a célula que receberá o valor do acerto
        With Range("F31")
            .Value = "Sub-Total:"
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'Mais uma etiqueta
        With Range("G31")
            .Formula = "=G29+G30"
            .FormulaHidden = True
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'Preparamos a célula que efectua o cálculo da soma dos valores
        'com o valor de acerto a efectuar
        With Range("F32")
            .Value = "Total (IVA):"
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        'Etiqueta da célula com o total
        'acrescido de IVA
        With Range("G32")
            .Formula = "=IF(Escola=""Dr. João Rocha - Pai"", G31, G31*1.23)"
            .FormulaHidden = True
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        'Preparamos a célula que efectua
        'o cálculo do valor acrescido de IVA
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'Activamos a actualização do ecrã
    ElseIf Not Me.cbAcertos Then
    'Caso não tenhamos de efectuar acertos
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Desligamos a actualização do ecrã
        With Range("F30")
            .Value = "Total (IVA):"
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        'Preparamos a etiqueta do total
        'acrescido de IVA
        With Range("F31")
            .ClearContents
        End With
        'Limpeza de células não actualizadas
        With Range("G30")
            .Formula = "=IF(Escola=""Dr. João Rocha - Pai"", G29, G29*1.23)"
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        'Preparamos a célula que efectua, agora,
        'o cálculo do total acrescido de IVA
        With Range("G31")
            .Formula = ""
        End With
        'Mais limpezas
        With Range("F32")
            .Value = ""
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        With Range("G32")
            .Formula = ""
            .FormulaHidden = False
            .NumberFormat = xlNone
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
Else
'Caso não tenhamos de acrescentar o acréscimo do AEV
    If Me.cbAcertos Then
        'Desligamos a actualização do ecrã
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Acrescentamos o texto
        With Range("F28")
            .Value = "Valor Acerto:"
        End With
        'Limpamos e desbloqueamos a célula que recebe o valor do acerto
        With Range("G28")
            .ClearContents
        End With
        'Acrescentamos a célula que recebe a soma
        'entre o valor das refeições e o valor do acerto
        With Range("F29")
            .Value = "Sub-Total:"
            .FormulaHidden = True
        End With
        With Range("G29")
            .Formula = "=G27+G28"
        End With
        'Acrescentamos a célula que recebe o valor total
        'acrescido de IVA
        With Range("F30")
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = "Total (IVA):"
        End With
        'Acrescentamos o cálculo do IVA caso
        'não sejam refeições do AEV
        With Range("G30")
            .FormulaHidden = True
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Formula = "=IF(Escola=""Dr. João Rocha - Pai"", G29, G29*1.23)"
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
        End With
        'Acrescentamos a border dupla para indicar a soma
        Range("F30:G30").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
        Range("F30:G30").Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
        'Activamos a actualização do ecrã
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox Range("C24").Locked
    ElseIf Not Me.cbAcertos Then
    'Caso não existam acertos desactivamos o ecrã
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Alteramos o conteúdo da célula para indicar
        'o total acrescido de IVA
        With Range("F28")
            .Value = "Total (IVA):"
        End With
        'Limpamos o conteúdo nas restantes células
        With Range("F29")
            .ClearContents
        End With
        'Alteramos a formula existente
        With Range("G28")
            .Formula = "=IF(Escola=""Dr. João Rocha - Pai"", G27, G27*1.23)"
        End With
        'Mais limpezas
        With Range("G29")
            .Formula = ""
        End With
        With Range("F30")
            .ClearContents
        End With
        With Range("G30")
            .Formula = ""
        End With
        With Range("F30:G30")
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'Activamos a actualização do ecrã
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If

Call protectWindow

End Sub
```

This should not be happening and the user should be able to always edit unlocked cells whithout the MsgBox hack.
Can anyone spot an error with the code and suggest corrections?

I am adding the code for protectWindow and unProtectWindow. Protection is necessary because some of the cells are locked.

```
Sub protectWindow()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Formulário")

wb.Protect pwd, Structure:=True, Windows:=True
With ws
    .Protect pwd
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With

End Sub

Sub unProtectWindow()

With ThisWorkbook
    .Unprotect pwd
    .Worksheets("Formulário").Unprotect pwd
End With

End Sub
```

Could this be somekind of a bug?

Comment: Can you share the code for `Call protectWindow`?

Comment: Added the code @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1):

You want your cells to remain unlocked, correct? If so, then you shouldn't be calling protectWindow at the end of your Sub. You can unlock any range by setting its Locked property to false or any workbook by using the Unprotect Method:

```
Sub UnlockingCells()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G37").Locked = False 
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact the protection is necessary. There are some locked cells. The strangest part is that the result of MsgBox Range("C24").Locked is False, meaning that the cell isn't indeed locked. This does not serve has a solution, but thanks.